# Draw line after picture box zoom

Tags: c#, drawing, draw

Iam using a user define picture box on my project, its working fine with zooming the image and any element already drawn on the image(line,text,shapes ......) the element position is transferred to the right position after zooming.
the problem appears when i am trying to draw a line after zooming, check this image

[image]

the drawn element is drawn with offset from the mouse position, this is the drawing code

this is paint function inside mt user define picture box

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (_image == null)
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        return;
    }
    Matrix mx = new Matrix(_zoom, 0, 0, _zoom, 0, 0);
    mx.Translate(this.AutoScrollPosition.X / _zoom, this.AutoScrollPosition.Y / _zoom);
    Matrix Tempmx = e.Graphics.Transform;
    e.Graphics.Transform = mx;
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = _interpolationMode;//ClipRectangle = {X = 0 Y = 0 Width = 1234 Height = 651}
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, new Rectangle(this.position.X, this.position.Y, this._image.Width, this._image.Height), 0, 0, _image.Width, _image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

this is paint function inside the line sprite

```
public override void Draw(Graphics g)
{
    Pen DrawPen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(BaseColor));
    g.DrawLine(DrawPen, this.position, this.position2);

    if (isSelected)
    {
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black));
        g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, new Rectangle(this.position.X, this.position.Y, 5, 5));
        g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, new Rectangle(this.position2.X, this.position2.Y, 5, 5));
    }
}
```

i think this problem is due to the transform matrix but i am not sure how to solve it, so any help how to solve this  ?

EDIT:
if the problem is not clear, the problem is:
after zooming the image in the picture box and trying to draw a line on the image, the drawn lin is drawn with offset from the mouse position not in the same position, see thispicture when iam drawing without zooming(every thing is fine)

[image]

this one after zooming(the line should be drawn on the mouse position when moving, see how its been drawn with an offset)

[image]

Comment: Not Clear question, edit it please for better understanding..!!

Comment: it might be issue in calculating the values of position and position2. How do you assign these values ? ie. are you changing the values of position with respect to ZOOM In/Out ?

Comment: position and position2 are not calculated vales its just the mouse positions on mouse downe and mouse move ...

Comment: Do you mean position = new point (e.X,e.Y); with any changes ? from your mouse postion

Comment: this.position = e.Location